# Does the requirement asked in this query makes sense?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have solved 99% challenges in sql in skillrack.com which is a site for practicing coding for placements, this is the last one, I cant even understand the question itself, I think there is a conceptual error in question, If you have time, you can read the question and help me out, thank you reading this.

A table called movie is created with the following DDL command.

The Table Schema

```
create table movie(
    id int, 
    name varchar(15), 
    releaseyear int, 
    budget int
);
```

Write the SQL query to fetch the id, name, release year and budget of the highest budget movies in each year.

Note: The movies must be sorted in descending order based on the budget. If two or more movies have the same budget, then those movies must be sorted in descending order based on the release year. If two or more movies have the same budget and release year, then those movies must be sorted in descending order based on their ids.

The data in Database

```
501 Movie1 2018 850000000 
502 Movie2 2018 800000000 
503 Movie3 2018 850000000 
504 Movie4 2018 750000000 
505 Movie5 2019 850000000 
506 Movie6 2019 950000000 
507 Movie7 2019 900000000 
508 Movie8 2019 500000000 
509 Movie9 2019 850000000 
510 Movie10 2020 800000000 
511 Movie11 2020 700000000 
512 Movie12 2020 600000000 
513 Movie13 2020 990000000 
514 Movie14 2017 920000000 
515 Movie15 2017 910000000 
516 Movie16 2021 990000000
```

Required Output

```
516 Movie16 2021 990000000 
513 Movie13 2020 990000000 
506 Movie6 2019 950000000 
514 Movie14 2017 920000000 
509 Movie9 2019 850000000 
505 Movie5 2019 850000000 
503 Movie3 2018 850000000 
501 Movie1 2018 850000000
```

I dont know why the movie id with 509 and 505 has been in required output,since the year 2019 has the maximum budget as 950000000, If you find any logic to clarify, I highly appreciate it.

Comment: I agree with @RiggsFolly as it should only be 1 movie per year unless there are 2 or more with the same highest budget

Comment: In my opinion the question was simply wrong and was asking all movies to be listed based on their budget descending, then by year descending and then by id descending. IOW required output doesn't match the question. It is a pity tutorial has error but you can encounter errors in documentation and tutorials. Required output is wrong in any case and the question is wrong.

Comment: *why the movie id with 509 and 505 has been in required output,since the year 2019 has the maximum budget as 950000000* Looks like an error in the desireв output. Maybe the question aim is to find this incorrectness?

Comment: Since both question and required outputs are wrong, finding correct output for the question (ignoring highest word - just the sorts) and also as a separate query for finding highest budget films per year, you are good to go for that task, don't get hooked to wrong output.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Don't think all movies are requested to be listed, as the  sample output has significantly less entries than the table has. `509` and `505` simply shouldn't be part of the output – and I'd have considered it more meaningful to finally sort by name instead of id, but that's another matter...

Comment: @Aconcagua, we don't know that. As I said, output doesn't match the question. There is a mismatch, so we don't know what is really required. It might be both a wrong and less than needed rows output, or might be simply a wrong output matching the question as you said.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Well, without these two rows the output *would* match the question. There's no certainty, but at least quite some likeliness, as this requires the least number of changes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you posted the integral and correct text for the question the required output is wrong.

The required output should look like this:

```
516 Movie16 2021 990000000
513 Movie13 2020 990000000 
506 Movie6 2019 950000000 
514 Movie14 2017 920000000 
501 Movie1 2018 850000000 
503 Movie3 2018 850000000
```

I don't know Skillrack but usually similar websites implement a reporting system for wrong answers or ambiguous question to be examined by moderators.

I suggest you read again the question and confirm that the request is in fact correct as you posted it, if it is report the question to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an answer, since I agree with you that the question doesn't make sense)

I would suggest you to solve these, if you can than you are ok:

```
create table movie(
    id int, 
    name varchar(15), 
    releaseyear int, 
    budget int
);

INSERT INTO movie
VALUES
  (501, 'Movie1',  2018, 850000000),
  (502, 'Movie2',  2018, 800000000),
  (503, 'Movie3',  2018, 850000000),
  (504, 'Movie4',  2018, 750000000),
  (505, 'Movie5',  2019, 850000000),
  (506, 'Movie6',  2019, 950000000),
  (507, 'Movie7',  2019, 900000000),
  (508, 'Movie8',  2019, 500000000),
  (509, 'Movie9',  2019, 850000000),
  (510, 'Movie10', 2020, 800000000),
  (511, 'Movie11', 2020, 700000000),
  (512, 'Movie12', 2020, 600000000),
  (513, 'Movie13', 2020, 990000000),
  (514, 'Movie14', 2017, 920000000),
  (515, 'Movie15', 2017, 910000000),
  (516, 'Movie16', 2021, 990000000);
```

Query1: List all the movies, sorting them as in the question.

Expected output:

| id | name | releaseyear | budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 516 | Movie16 | 2021 | 990000000 |
| 513 | Movie13 | 2020 | 990000000 |
| 506 | Movie6 | 2019 | 950000000 |
| 514 | Movie14 | 2017 | 920000000 |
| 515 | Movie15 | 2017 | 910000000 |
| 507 | Movie7 | 2019 | 900000000 |
| 509 | Movie9 | 2019 | 850000000 |
| 505 | Movie5 | 2019 | 850000000 |
| 503 | Movie3 | 2018 | 850000000 |
| 501 | Movie1 | 2018 | 850000000 |
| 510 | Movie10 | 2020 | 800000000 |
| 502 | Movie2 | 2018 | 800000000 |
| 504 | Movie4 | 2018 | 750000000 |
| 511 | Movie11 | 2020 | 700000000 |
| 512 | Movie12 | 2020 | 600000000 |
| 508 | Movie8 | 2019 | 500000000 |

Query2: List only the movies with the highest budget per year, sorting them as in the question.

Expected output:

| id | name | releaseyear | budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 516 | Movie16 | 2021 | 990000000 |
| 513 | Movie13 | 2020 | 990000000 |
| 506 | Movie6 | 2019 | 950000000 |
| 514 | Movie14 | 2017 | 920000000 |
| 503 | Movie3 | 2018 | 850000000 |
| 501 | Movie1 | 2018 | 850000000 |

Please try solving on your own first and then check the solution (there are other ways to solve it, just one them even applicable to very old versions of any SQL  series database):

[DBfiddle solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/vnK1lON5)