# Can anyone provide SQL query to fetch the id, name, release year and budget of the highest budget movies in each year?

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

Problem Statement:

A table called movie is created with the following DDL command.

`create table movie(id int, name varchar(15), releaseyear int, budget int);`

Write the SQL query to fetch the id, name, release year and budget of the highest budget movies in each year.
Note: The movies must be sorted in descending order based on the budget. If two or more movies have the same budget, then those movies must be sorted in descending order based on the release year. If two or more movies have the same budget and release year, then those movies must be sorted in descending order based on their ids. Also 'with' clause is not allowed.

[[[Problem image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlAbr.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm9XG.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myR31.jpg)

This is my SQL query:

```
select m.id,m.name,m.releaseyear,m.budget 
from movie m 
join (select releaseyear,max(budget) as maxbudget from movie group by releaseyear) mm 
on m.releaseyear=mm.releaseyear and m.budget=mm.maxbudget 
order by budget desc, releaseyear desc, id desc;
```

Table movie contains:

```
501 Movie1 2018 850000000 
502 Movie2 2018 800000000 
503 Movie3 2018 850000000 
504 Movie4 2018 750000000 
505 Movie5 2019 850000000 
506 Movie6 2019 950000000 
507 Movie7 2019 900000000 
508 Movie8 2019 500000000 
509 Movie9 2019 850000000 
510 Movie10 2020 800000000 
511 Movie11 2020 700000000 
512 Movie12 2020 600000000 
513 Movie13 2020 990000000 
514 Movie14 2017 920000000 
515 Movie15 2017 910000000 
516 Movie16 2021 990000000
```

Expected output:

```
516 Movie16 2021 990000000 
513 Movie13 2020 990000000 
506 Movie6 2019 950000000 
514 Movie14 2017 920000000 
509 Movie9 2019 850000000 
505 Movie5 2019 850000000 
503 Movie3 2018 850000000 
501 Movie1 2018 850000000
```

My output:

```
516 Movie16 2021 990000000 
513 Movie13 2020 990000000 
506 Movie6 2019 950000000 
514 Movie14 2017 920000000 
503 Movie3 2018 850000000 
501 Movie1 2018 850000000
```

Can anyone help me to get expected output?

Comment: [tag:mysql] <> [tag:oracle]

Comment: Why does your expected output for 2019 include movies with a 850M budget which is lower than 2019's maximum budget of 950M?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75509991/1048425) where the general consensus is that the answer on Skill Rack is not correct. Your query and results look fine to me

Comment: You should use row-numbering instead. `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY releaseyear ORDER BY budget DESC)` and the filter that result to 1

Comment: @Saran Kumar S Can you chech the below Answer and accept it if its working

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the expected output, you need to adjust the ordering in your query. The primary ordering should be based on the budget in descending order. If budgets are the same, then you should consider the release year, and if both budgets and release years are the same, then you should consider the ID in descending order. Your query seems correct for the most part, but the ordering needs some adjustments.

Here's the modified query:

```sql
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.releaseyear, m.budget 
FROM movie m 
JOIN (
    SELECT releaseyear, MAX(budget) AS maxbudget 
    FROM movie 
    GROUP BY releaseyear
) mm ON m.releaseyear = mm.releaseyear AND m.budget = mm.maxbudget 
ORDER BY m.budget DESC, m.releaseyear DESC, m.id DESC;
```

In this query, `ORDER BY` now uses `m.budget`, `m.releaseyear`, and `m.id` instead of just `budget`, `releaseyear`, and `id`. This ensures that the ordering is applied correctly based on the columns from the `movie` table. With these adjustments, you should get the expected output.

Comment: @Saran Can you check the Answer and accept it?